# Loading txt file as an asset for a dart package

Tags: dart

In flutter it's easy to load a .txt asset at runtime by specifying it or its folder in the pubspec.yaml file and then loading it with `rootBundle`. However, i'm working on a pure dart package, and I'm struggling to work out how to get the package to load a .txt file relative to it's own directory structure.

When I use the package in a separate dart command line application i'm working on, the relative path that I specified in one of the package source code files causes an error to be thrown that the txt file doesn't exist. I understand why this error is being thrown, because the relative path is interpreted as being from the command line application's root directory instead of the package's root directory, but i'm unsure of how to solve this without specifying the absolute path for the .txt file. I'd rather not specify the absolute path as it makes the package less portable.

Is there anything similar to flutter's asset loading for a pure dart package?

Comment: Is this "pure Dart package" intended to be used in Flutter apps?

Comment: It is not. It's for a dart command line application only.

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible, then. There used to be a `Resource` class in Dart, which was deprecated in favor of the resource package. The resource package was discontinued with the understanding that most Dart code nowadays is AOT compiled, at which point there is no way to get the location of a specific source file. Instead, what you should probably do is write your package assets into Dart files, and if there's anything that needs to be tweaked by end users, have those files be generated in the program's root directory when the utility is first run and then loaded on subsequent runs.

Comment: Ah ok, that's what i feared. By write package assets into Dart files, do you mean put them into list and map literals ect?

Comment: Essentially, yeah. Anything you need to load at runtime from your package that isn't code should be wrapped in a Dart file, whether that's as a list, map, or even just a massive string literal.

Comment: To automatically wrap assets in dart files, [aspen](https://pub.dev/packages/aspen) package is perhaps useful (unfortunately it has not been updated to null safety)

Comment: I use [mason](https://github.com/felangel/mason/) to bundle assets in my CLIs

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the [resolveSymbolicLinks](http://resolveSymbolicLinks) or [resolveSymbolicLinksSync](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.4/dart-io/FileSystemEntity/resolveSymbolicLinksSync.html) methods to decode the relative path and then use the resolved path to read the txt file:

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() async {
  String file = '../lib/main.dart';
  var path = Uri.parse('.').resolveUri(Uri.file(file)).toFilePath();
  print(path);
  if (path == '') path = '.';
  var resolved = await File(path).resolveSymbolicLinks();
  print(resolved);

  File(resolved).readAsString().then((String contents) {
    print(contents);
  });
}
```